# Как я могу убрать пропуск между header и aside?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@Charset "UTF-8";
* {
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #FAEEDD;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: comic sans ms, sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto/9;
}

.left {
  float: left
}

;
header,
footer {
  width: 98%;
  min-height: 50px;
}

aside {
  width: 400px;
  height: 605px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 3px solid grey;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 35px;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 0;
}

center {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 0px solid grey;
  background-color: #FAEEDD;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
  left: 500px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="englishfan.html" title="Homepage" id="logo"><img src="img/head1.jpg" alt="LearningEnglish" title="LearningEnglish" /></a>
</header>

<aside>
  <div id="menuhrefs"></div>
  <pre><a href="#"> Present simple</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Past simple</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Present continuous</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Past continuous</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Present perfect</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Past perfect</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Present perfect continuous</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Can, could</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Will, would</a>
     <hr><a href="#"> Reading</a></pre>
</aside>

<center>
  On this site you can find:<br><br>
  <span class="colortext">Basic grammar English rules</span> (you can learn the rules that are easy to understand and easy to learn).<br><br>
  <span class="colortext">Exercises in English</span> (you can do any exercises for present, past and future).<br><br>
  <span class="colortext">Tests reading</span> (if you want to do tests on READING you don't need pay for it, it’s all for free).<br><br>
</center>
```

Comment: Дайте `header` какой–нибудь класс и задайте `padding-bottom: 0px`

Comment: <header class="head">
 <a href="englishfan.html" title="Homepage" id="logo"><img src="img/head1.jpg" alt="LearningEnglish" title="LearningEnglish" /></a>
</header> и также теперь я не знаю куда мне вставить .head {padding-bottom: 0px}; потому что если я куда то вставляю в стилях то не работает.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Проверьте высоту картинки в хедере и высоту самого хедера, они могут быть разные.
2. Можно aside задать margin-top: -5px (5рх) это высота белой линии между хедером и асайдом

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло.

Comment: ок, жми стрелку вверх)